# Multiple Tab fragments inside bottom navigation fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, tabnavigator, android-bottomnav

In bottom navigation with three tabs (Home, Dashboard, Notifications). Each bottom navigation tab is a fragment. The first tab ie. Home fragment contains another top navigation tabs having four tabs (Tab 1, Tab 2, Tab 3, Tab 4).

[image]

**The problem**

1. When  navigate from **Home** tab to **Notifications** tab directly and come back to **Home** tab, Tab1/which ever tab previously selected tab (top navigation tabs) the content of the tab is not loaded.
2. When swipe the tabs from **Tab 1** (Home fragment tab) all the way to **Notification** tab and swipe back, on reaching the **Tab 4** the content of the tab is not loaded *and on first swipe from **Tab 4** to **Tab 3** the swipe does not take to **Tab 3**.* The tab indicator just move a little and on second swipe it goes to **Tab 3** as expected.

The app contains a lot of code so I'll just link the full code to [Github](https://github.com/PuniCharana/sample-app.git).

**For quick reference here are my codes**

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ViewPager viewPager;

    NavigationView navigationView;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hide the activity toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        //Initializing viewPager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);


        final BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_home);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_notifications);
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });


    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        BottomNavPagerAdapter adapter = new BottomNavPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new FirstFragment());
        adapter.addFragment(new SecondFragment());
        adapter.addFragment(new ThirdFragment());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

FirstFragment.java (Home)

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager firstViewPager;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

        firstViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_content);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(firstViewPager);

        setupViewPager(firstViewPager);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        TabViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Tab 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Tab 2");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Tab 3");
        adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Tab 4");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. What's wrong in code ?
2. How to solve this issues? (The layout is a requirement) or is there any better approach to come up with the layout from the screenshot?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Actually, it is a common mistake - you're using `FragmentManager` of your `Activity` inside the fragment, but since this fragment contains another **child** fragments you have to use `FragmentManager` of the fragment itself. So the fix is simple - you just have to change `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragmentManager()` inside your fragments, so the code will be:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    TabViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    ...
    ...
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And this should work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Try use `getChildFragmentManager()` instance of `getSupportFragmentManager()`.