# RecyclerView doesn't Show Data When Adding two fragments to FragmentManager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments with recyclerview. InteractionsFragment and its copy InteractionsFragmentCopy (exact same replica of InteractionsFragment). When I try to add them, only the one that gets added first its recyclerview data is displayed, the other fragment's recyclerview data is blank as shown on the screenshot:

[image]

---Activity code---

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private InteractionsFragment interactionsFragment = InteractionsFragment.newInstance();
private InteractionsFragmentCopy interactionsFragmentCopy = InteractionsFragmentCopy.newInstance();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container1, interactionsFragment).show(interactionsFragment).commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container2, interactionsFragmentCopy).show(interactionsFragmentCopy).commit();

}
}
```

---Layout file---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activities.HomeActivity"
android:background="@color/Blue">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/Yellow">

</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:background="@color/Yellow"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer here
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44561180/multiple-tab-fragments-inside-bottom-navigation-fragment)

It turned out that since I'm using viewpager inside the fragment then I hade to change the viewpager adapter instantiation from:

```
 InteractionsFragment.ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
```

to

```
InteractionsFragment.ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

That's fixed the issue